# Aligning parts of an equation system

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, equations

I'm trying to write down a pretty complicated formula with LaTeX. This is

[image]

what I want to obtain, and this is

[image]

is what I get with the following code:

```
\begin{equation*}
\left.\begin{aligned}
        min/max&&   f_{i}(x),&&                                 i=1,2,\dots,k;\\
        s.t.&&      g_{j}(x)\geq0,&&                            j=1,2,\dots,J;\\
            &&      h_{p}(x)=0,&&                               p=1,2,\dots,H;\\
            &&      x_{i}^{(L)} \leq x_{i} \leq x_{i}^{(U)},&&  i=1,2,\dots,n.
    \end{aligned}
\right\}
\end{equation*}
```

As you can see, in my version the three "columns" I'm trying to get are aligned on the right, I'd like to have them aligned on the left like in the first image.
I hope you won't cringe too much for my illiterate way of using "&", I just started with LaTeX a week ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
\left.\begin{aligned}
        \min/\max\  &   f_{i}(x),       &   i & = 1,2,\dots,k;  \\
             s.t.\  &   g_{j}(x)\geq0,  &   j & =1,2,\dots,J;   \\
                    &   h_{p}(x)=0,     &   p & =1,2,\dots,H;   \\
                    &   x_{i}^{(L)} \leq x_{i} \leq x_{i}^{(U)},
                                        &   i & =1,2,\dots,n.
    \end{aligned}
\right\}
\]
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

- you have correct number of ampersands, but heir positions was not correct :-). in aligned environment first ampersand determine anchor of aligning of equation, second separate columns in "multi columns" equation.
- since between `\min/\max` is not math operator (as `+`, `=` etc) whic provide some horizontal spacing i add `\`, which insert one space character between expressions
- `min` and `max` are operators defined in latex, so they had to be written as `\min` and `\max`
- for better spacing `\min/\max` i suggest to insert negative spaces `\!`: `\min\!/\!\max\` (i didn't consider this in above code)

Comment: This is even simpler! I was trying to understand how Mico's solution worked (that array approach looks handier for more complicated situations), but your solution just uses "\" and "&". Could you briefly explain to me how did you get the columns to align that perfectly?

Comment: hopefully i will, recently i experiences difficulties with uploading images and editing my answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % Times Roman clone
\begin{document}
\[
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
\left.\begin{array}{r@{\hspace{1.5mm}}l@{\quad}l@{}}
\min/\max & f_i(\mathbf{x}),     & i=1,2,\dots,k;\\
$s.t.$      & g_j(\mathbf{x})\ge0, & j=1,2,\dots,J;\\
            & h_p(\mathbf{x})=0,   & p=1,2,\dots,H;\\
            & x_i^{(L)}\leq x_i\leq x_i^{(H)},& i=1,2,\dots,n.
\end{array}\right\}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply forgot that `3 columns requires`5&`: each column requires 1 ampersand for the alignment point and one to ‘enter’ the *new* column.

Here are two simple ways to obtain what you want: in the place of the pair  `\left. ... \right\}`, you can either use the `rcases` environment from `mathtools` (which loads `amsmath`, or use the optional argument `[right=\empheqrbrace]` for the `empheq` environment, from the homonymous package (which loads `mathtools`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{rcases}
\begin{aligned}
        \min/\max&& & f_{i}(x),& i&=1,2,\dots,k;\\
        \text{s. t}.& & & g_{j}(x)\geq0,& j&=1,2,\dots,J;\\
            & & & h_{p}(x)=0,& p&=1,2,\dots,H;\\
            & & & x_{i}^{(L)} \leq x_{i} \leq x_{i}^{(U)},& i&=1,2,\dots,n.
    \end{aligned}
\end{rcases}
\end{equation*}
%

\begin{empheq}[right =\empheqrbrace]{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
        \min/\max&& & f_{i}(x),& i&=1,2,\dots,k;\\
        \text{s. t}.& & & g_{j}(x)\geq0,& j&=1,2,\dots,J;\\
            & & & h_{p}(x)=0,& p&=1,2,\dots,H;\\
            & & & x_{i}^{(L)} \leq x_{i} \leq x_{i}^{(U)},& i&=1,2,\dots,n.
    \end{aligned}
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]